# Need help with jquery checkboxes set

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checked

I have a DOM structure sometihng like this (I don't want to show other td's because of overcrowding):

```
<table>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" class="rowSelectCheckbox"></td></input></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" class="rowSelectCheckbox"></td></input></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" class="rowSelectCheckbox"></td></input></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" class="rowSelectCheckbox"></td></input></tr>

</table>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_select" id="lastCheckbox"></input>
```

What I'm trying to do is set the last checkbox with the id of lastCheckbox to checked if **any** of the other checkboxes are checked (any of those with id of checkbox1, checkbox 2 etc), otherwise if **all** the other checkboxes are unchecked, set this last checkbox to unchecked too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.rowSelectCheckbox').change( function() {
    $('.rowSelectCheckbox').each( function() {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('#lastCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
            return false;
        }

        $('#lastCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
    } );
} );
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B78vP/

Comment: Thanks mate, I saw it on the link you provided. It worked like a charm.

Comment: Not to smack you down, but looping thru anything with `.rowSelectCheckbox` is kind of a little wasteful :/ You only need to check if one of `.rowSelectCheckbox` is checked (rather than all)

Answer (score 1):

One little niggle: the closing `</input>` tag belongs before the `</td>` tag.

Otherwise it's pretty straightforward.

```
$(".rowSelectCheckbox").click(function(){
    var lastCheckbox = $("#lastCheckbox");
    if $(".rowSelectCheckbox:checked").length) {
        lastCheckbox.attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        lastCheckbox.removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
$('.rowSelectCheckbox').change( function() {
    flag = false;
    $('.rowSelectCheckbox').each( function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            flag = true;
        }
    });    
    $('#lastCheckbox').prop('checked', flag);
});
```

Live demonstration here: http://jsfiddle.net/nayish/teXHe/

Comment: It seems not to be working for some reason... actually it seems way too complicated for me, though I'm desperate for this snippet

Comment: Edited answer, I had it wrong before, only worked when all checkboxes were checked. Should work now :)

Comment: Yeah, just checked the demo. Works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A quick if-test should do this:

```
$("input.rowSelectCheckbox").change(function(){
    if ( $("input.rowSelectCheckbox:checked") ) { //include "rowSelectCheckbox" so id=lastCheckbox doesn't trip the test
        $("input#lastCheckbox").attr("checked");
    }
    else
        $("input#lastCheckbox").removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
```

A loop, such as .each(), is unnecessary since you only care if (any) **one** of `input.rowSelectCheckbox` is checked. This will return true the first time it encounters an `<input class="rowSelectCheckbox" />` that is checked ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following jQuery should do the trick

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rowSelectCheckbox").click(function() {
        var numChecked = $(".rowSelectCheckbox").filter(":checked").length;

        if(numChecked > 0)
        {
            $("#lastCheckbox").prop("checked", "checked");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#lastCheckbox").prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
});
```

This will count the number of checked checkboxes when any one of them is clicked and, if this number is greater than 0, check the last checkbox outside the table.

There's a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/V595j/).